# How to attach nodes and links to simulation force in d3js version 4?

Tags: d3.js

I try to port to d4.v4.js some graph drawing built with version 3.
I quite don't understand how to attach svg nodes and links to the simulation with atlas force. 
The simplified version using d3.v3 is shared on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/vf9x0x88/), note that all nodes are grouped in a `<g>` element, and each node, simplified as a circle in this example is inserted in a `<g>` element as well. Similarly, links are grouped in a `<g>` element. I need those to draw more complexe networks.

```
svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");

var force = d3.layout.force()
.gravity(.15)
.distance(100)
.charge(-1200)
.friction(0.8)
.size([width, height]);

// push initial sets of nodes and links
var nodes = force.nodes(), links = force.links();
Array.prototype.push.apply(nodes, data.nodes);
Array.prototype.push.apply(links, data.edges);
```

My reference for drawing a network with d3.v4 in shared on [fiddle as well](https://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/tokbs3vg/), it actually works, however each node is not in a `<g>` element as required (I guess) for my more complex graphs.

This [last fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pducrot/7jyytsLs/) shows the d3.v4 version of the simplified graph, as one can see, nodes remain in the upper left corner, only zoom works.

```
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.call(zoom);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("link", d3.forceLink()
       .id(function(d) { return d.id; })
       .distance(function(d) { return (1-d.value*d.value*d.value)*20; }))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-200))
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

var pane = svg.append("g");

var link = pane.append("g")
.attr("class", "links")
.selectAll("line")
.data(graph.links)
.enter().append("line")
.attr("class", "link")
.style("stroke-width", function(d) { return d.value*d.value*d.value*10; });

var node = pane.append("g")
.attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")
.data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("class", "node")
.attr("r", function(d) { return d.value*5   })
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

My question is how should I attach nodes (`<g>`) and links to "simulation"? What is wrong in my script?
Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your last fiddle with the d3v4 implementation.
2 changes and it will work.

1) the `ticked` function to move the elements. Since nodes are svg groups now, you can't use `cx` and `cy` attributes (good for circles). You need to use `transform translate` like this:

```
node
  .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; 
  });
```

2) The `node` variable there contains only the *update selection*, since you called the *enter selection* `nodeEnter`. And since all elements are in the enter selection (just created), you don't move anything.
So you just need to merge the two selections like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) { return d.value*10 })
node.exit().remove();
node = nodeEnter.merge(node);
```

You can read more details in Mike Bostock [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_merge) about this. Check also [this](https://bl.ocks.org/HarryStevens/bc938c8d45008d99faed47039fbe5d49) and other similar bl.ocks.

To correctly target the links in `ticked` you should also merge enter and update link selections in the same way.

As a side note, you don't need to link source and target objects in the links as you do in `getGraph` function, since this is done by d3 `simulation` already. So you could just use your `json` object as data.

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/miromarchi/zpueh325/).
Hope it is clearer how to upgrade d3 v3 force directed layout to d3 v4 force simulation :D